# String to arrays

Tags: javascript

I have below String  that needs to be divided into multiple array after 5 comma separated values. Then I need to put each array values to textbox values using script. I tried the below code to split and assign to array but not working. Is there any way this can be resolved?  `<%=ab%>` is the JavaScript variable that contains the below code.

`[768.234.232, 768.234.232, 574,10-10-2012, 10-10-2012, 768.234.232, 768.234.232, 987, 10-10-2012, 10-10-2012]`

```
function functionOne() {
    var list = "<%=ab%>";
    var ab = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ab[i] = list.split(",", 3);
        alert(ab[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the values were quoted, it would be simple JSON.

Comment: values are like [768.234.232, 768.234.232, 574, 768.234.232, 768.234.232, 987]  without any quotes. But my main issue is spliting and assigning to different arrays.

Comment: Do you have any idea what your code is doing? I see a `list` variable, that contains a constant, 7 character string, a variable `ab` that is filled with pieces of `list` and a variable `array` that is alerted while it doesn't exist. I'd say: back to the drawing board.

Comment: `<%=ab%>` is a JavaScript variable?

Comment: <%=ab%> is java variable. This contains the string [768.234.232, 768.234.232, 574, 768.234.232, 768.234.232, 987]

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same...

Comment: You must use `ajax` (maybe) to call a method on your server, which will contain the string in question. In that method, serialise it, then pass it back to the client. This is what u must do.

Comment: @War10ck I know that and we'll be able to read JAVA VAriables in JavaScript by following the that step that I did. This works.

Comment: May I know why so many -ve votes on this question?

Comment: So to be clear, what technologies/languages are you using? This question is tagged JavaScript but you keep referring to Java. They are not the same...

Comment: @War10ck - The OP has used Java to return a string into a JavaScript function, and now wants that JavaScript function to manipulate the string.

Comment: @nnnnnn That's what I was guessing but seeing as the OP can't clearly explain what they want, I figure the question is pretty much doomed.

Comment: @War10ck please stop guessing. nnnnnn thanks again for your perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"needs to be divided into multiple array after 5 comma seperated values"*

You seem to be saying that the result should be one array with five values in it and then a second array with the next five values in it, etc. If so, you can do the following:

```
var list = "<%=ab%>";
list = list.slice(1,-1);                 // remove the enclosing []
var allValues = list.split(/\s*,\s*/);   // split on comma with optional whitespace
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i+=5) {
    a.push( allValues.slice(i, i+5<=allValues.length ? i+5 : allValues.length) );
}
```

After running the above, `a` will be array that contains other arrays. `a[0]` is an array of the first five items, so, e.g., `a[0][2]` is the third item. `a[1]` is an array of the next five items. If there were more than ten items in the original list then `a[2]` would be an array of the next five, etc. If the total number of items is not divisible by five then the last array would hold the remainder.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9xAxz/

> *"Then I need to put each array values to textbox values"*

Um... does that mean one item per textbox? If so, why did you want to divide up after five values? Do you mean five items per textbox? Either way are you talking about dynamically creating textboxes? If so you can follow the above code with something like this:

```
var tb;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    tb = document.createElement('input');
    tb.value = a[i].join(", ");
    document.body.appendChild(tb);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9xAxz/1/

If I'm completely off base on any of the above, well... think about editing your question to make it clearer. I suppose I should've clarified before answering, but please update the question to show what your desired output is for that input.

Comment: this is what exactly I am looking. Thank you very much. Few people didn't understand this and just marked the question down. Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. The reason the question was downvoted is that it was really not clear what you were trying to achieve. I made some guesses, and much as I like to think they were educated guesses really I just got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionOne() {
    var list = "<%=ab%>".split(/,\s?/g);

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        t = document.createElement('input');
        t.type = 'text';
        t.value = list[i];
        document.body.appendChild(t);
    }
}
functionOne();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WJPHt/1/

Comment: 768.234.232768.234.232574,10-10-201210-10-2012768.234.232768.234.23298710-10-201210-10-2012 is the O/P of above code @Samuel

Comment: Samuel thanks for trying to help me. Yes, the desired output is not what I was looking. @nnnnnn has answered my question perfectly. Thank you.